# first day of the week in MacOS X with c

Tags: c, macos, glibc

In Russia the first day of the week is Monday. In the United States - Sunday. On Linux `nl_langinfo(_NL_TIME_FIRST_WEEKDAY)` return 0 for Sun or 1 for Mon. How do I get too in MacOS X with c-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but from skimming the docs, you can get a `CFLocale` instance ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/Reference/reference.html)) and get it's `CFCalendar` instance using:

```
CFLocaleGetValue(locale, kCFLocaleCalendar)
```

And get the first day of the week from the `CFCalendar` instance using `CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday()` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFCalendarRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday)).

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use `CFDateRef` and `CFLocaleRef` opaque types and associated `CFDate*` and `CFLocale*` functions from CoreFoundation framework.

**UPDATE**

After some digging I found the function you need. It appears that you have to use `CFCalendar`  for this. From apple's documentation:

`CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday`
Returns the index of first weekday for a specified calendar.

```
CFIndex CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday (
   CFCalendarRef calendar
);
```

**Parameters**

*calendar*

The calendar to examine.

*Return Value*

The index of the first weekday of the specified calendar.